# Youtube api - Fetch news channel videos for spesific country?

Tags: php, api, video, youtube

I can get news channel videos by

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet
&channelId=UCYfdidRxbB8Qhf0Nx7ioOYw
&maxResults=5&key={APIKEY}
```

However, when I add country code `&regionCode=TR`, it still fetches the global news videos. How can I fetch news channel videos for spesific country